# Magento 2 Admin forgot password email password link not showing

Tags: magento2

I am trying to forgot password of magento2 admin, I am getting mail successfully but link not showing in email.

anyone have idea why this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

I already experienced this issue.

The code inside the **password_reset.html** file was changed in latest magento.